# MemoryStream, how many bytes in kb?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stream, filesize, memorystream

I'm using .net core to upload an image file. The file is converted to a MemoryStream and then sent to a service which will validate the file. Currently I do that with something like this:

```
MemoryStream stream = GetMemoryStream();
var fileSize = stream.length;
```

Now I want to ensure that the image is not larger than 512 kb. My problem is that I'm not sure what value to use to convert to bytes, 1024 or 1000? Should I use the decimal or binary values when listing length from MemoryStream?

Which scenario is correct?

Scenario A

```
if(fileSize > 512000) return false;
```

Scenario B

```
if(fileSize > 524288) return false;
```

EDIT:

When I look at properties of an image on my desktop and it says 512KB. Which scenario did the computer use to calculate that size?

Comment: _I want to ensure ..._  So it is _your_ rule. That means you can pick 1000, 1024 or even 1010. Whatever you like.

Comment: @HenkHolterman see my edit please.

Comment: "Which scenario did the computer use to calculate that size" - if you're using Windows, right click on the file in File Explorer and select Properties.  It will give you the file size in bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MemoryStream.Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.length?view=netframework-4.8) returns the length of the contained data in bytes.

Therefore, your validation completely depends on your definition of `512 kb`. So both of your scenarios are somewhat true; in the first one you assume that `1 kb = 1000 bytes`, and in the second one you assume that `1 kb = 1024 bytes`. It is up to you to decide which fits your application better.

Regarding your edit, the value used for a kilobyte on your computer depends on the OS you are using. E.g., on Windows it is [1024 bytes](https://superuser.com/questions/938234/size-of-files-in-windows-os-its-kb-or-kb).

Comment: So when I Upload a file which is 513 kb, how do I make sure that it fails? Which of the two values do I use to fail it?

Comment: @HenkHolterman This is true, I tried to shed some light on the misconception in the question here. I edited the answer to address the edit in the question.